# version control for one file used in multiple projects

Tags: version-control

If I have one file which is used by two projects, then at the moment I keep a copy in each of the relevant repositories. If I update one of them, is it possible to automagically synchronise the other? Softlinks wouldn't work (at least [not for Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961016/how-to-treat-a-symbolic-link-as-a-directory-in-mercurial)).

Edit: just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309350/version-controlling-database-that-is-used-by-multiple-projects). Is that a duplicate/is that the best way to fix my problem?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could consider [hardlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) your file in one of the two repositories. This can be a bit dangerous, though, so I wouldn't really recommend it. Maybe just check it out if you can't find anything else.

EDIT: It you're looking to synchronize a directory, this won't work. Hardlinking directories is just a bad idea, and is impossible (for good reason) on many systems.